# redux way of doing doesn't work for my sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- I am trying to learn redux.
- I am trying to add favorites functionality through Redux.
- so I created actions addFavoriteSPORTSs, reducers SPORTSReducer, and then  dispatched in tab-demo.js where i am doing mapDispatchToProps and
  mapStateToProps
- when I click the heart icon I am adding favorites in session storage  window.sessionStorage.setItem(
      "favoriteValues",
      JSON.stringify(action.payload)
    );
- but the problem is after the refresh the color is not staying in the heart.
- I debugged in componentDidMount and I am able to print the favotites get item value but still colr not maintaining.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- so that in future I will fix itmyself.
- providing my code snippet below

https://codesandbox.io/s/5x02vjjlqp

**actions/index.js**

```
import {
  ADD_SPORTS,
  DELETE_SPORTS,
  DELETE_ALL_SPORTS,
  ADD_ALL_SPORTSS
} from "./types";

export const addFavoriteSPORTSs = data => ({
  type: ADD_ALL_SPORTSS,
  payload: data
});
```

**actions/types.js**

```
export const ADD_ALL_SPORTSS = "ADD_ALL_SPORTSS";
```

**tab-demo.js**

```
import { deleteAllPosts, addFavoriteSPORTSs } from "./actions/index";

  componentDidMount() {
    let favorites = window.sessionStorage.getItem("favoriteValues");
    console.log("componentDidMount favorites--->", favorites);

    if (favorites) {
      this.props.addFavoriteSPORTSs(JSON.parse(favorites));
    }
    // debugger;
  }


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onDeleteAllSPORTS: () => {
      // console.log("called");
      dispatch(deleteAllPosts());
    },
    addFavoriteSPORTSs: data => {
      dispatch(addFavoriteSPORTSs(data));
    }
  };
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    SPORTSs: state.SPORTSs
  };
};

export default withStyles(styles)(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(ScrollableTabsButtonForce)
);
```

**SPORTSReducer.js**

```
switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ALL_SPORTSS:
      window.sessionStorage.setItem(
        "favoriteValues",
        JSON.stringify(action.payload)
      );
      return action.payload;

    case ADD_SPORTS:
      state = state.filter(comment => comment.id !== action.payload.id);
      value = [...state, action.payload];
      console.log("ADD_SPORTS state--->", state);
      console.log("ADD_SPORTS value--->", value);
      //return [...state, action.payload];

      // state = state.filter(SPORTS => SPORTS.SPORTSID !== action.payload.SPORTSID);
      // value = [...state, action.payload]
      window.sessionStorage.setItem("favoriteValues", JSON.stringify(value));
      console.log("JSON.stringify(value)--->", JSON.stringify(value));
      console.log("state--->", state);
      return state;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the component mounts you retrieve your favourties and set the redux state via calling your prop method. Your component will receive this new state via mapStateToProps, but it won't update without a suitable lifecycle method like componentDidUpdate or componentWillReceiveProps.

You can check out the lifecycle methods [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html).

Also, you are mutating your state in redux which is something you want to avoid. See this line:

```
state = state.filter(comment => comment.id !== action.payload.id);
```

I would also recommend Redux middleware for these tasks. You can set up middleware that will write to session storage whenever a specific action occurs and you can then rehyrdate Redux from that as well.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply... for one week I am stuck with it...can you update directly in my sandbox...its so confusing :(  https://codesandbox.io/s/5x02vjjlqp

Comment: You can see here https://codesandbox.io/s/kzyp17yj3. I updated the reducer and tab-demo. I'm not going to write all of the code for you so you'll have to figure out how to update your UI state. You probably want to use getDerivedStateFromProps rather than componentDidUpdate like I used here.

Comment: I read through this article but still I am not sure how to avoid mutate since I am using filter method...can you provide some suggestions https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns

Comment: thanks so much for your explaination but I am not able to see your changes....can you give comments in your code...it will be very helpful

Comment: Search for "componentDidUpdate": in tab-demo. That's the only thing I added. In your reducer I added a new variable called "newstate" to avoid mutation.

Comment: I further debugged your code, do I need to update my state in the Redux middleware way and can you tell me why you have included this if condition here ----> if (prevProps.SPORTSs !== this.props.SPORTSs) {

Comment: No, you don't need to use middleware but it will make your code simpler. You should read up on lifecycle methods as they are fundamental to React: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate. You need to have a condition in componentDidUpdate to avoid an infinite loop.

Comment: can you tell me why you suggested getDerivedStateFromProps  instead of componentDidUpdate and in the sandbox you have used componentDidUpdate

Comment: componentDidUpdate, componentWillReceiveProps and getDerivedStateFromProps are all suitable. I picked one to show you how you can detect prop changes and update state. I mentioned getDerivedStateFromProps because it might be more appropriate depending on your use case and I wanted to make you aware of it. You should read the documentation and find out if it is more suitable for you. componentWillReceiveProps will be deprecated so you should avoid that although it's a bit easier to understand.

Comment: hey I thought about the logic but still I am not able to figure it out how to achieve in updating the stae...can you please help me